# I cannot understand the meaning and mechanism of @ in numpy simd vectorized code

Tags: c, numpy, macros, simd

I am solving issue of bounty source shown below

https://www.bountysource.com/issues/73221262-optimize-numpy-simd-algorithms-for-power-vsx

And I have to understand simd vectorized code in numpy shown below

https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/src/umath/simd.inc.src#L222

And I found many "@" in source code. It's like substituting string.

like this

```
/**begin repeat
 * #TYPE = CFLOAT, CDOUBLE#
 * #type= npy_float, npy_double#
 * #esize = 8, 16#
 */
```

this is like list of substitution string

```
   static NPY_INLINE int
run_binaryavx512f@func@_@TYPE@(char **args, const npy_intp *dimensions, const npy_intp *steps)
{
#if defined HAVE_ATTRIBUTE_TARGET_AVX512F_WITH_INTRINSICS && defined NPY_HAVE_SSE2_INTRINSICS
    if (IS_BINARY_STRIDEONE(@esize@, 64)) {
        AVX512F@func@_@TYPE@(args, dimensions, steps);
        return 1;
    }
    else
        return 0;
#endif
    return 0;
}
```

But I cannnot understand the mechanism of substituting string.
I cannot find document about this at all.

Can you give an explanation?

Comment: It's pretty clearly some kind of macro language (other than CPP), maybe to kind of tempelate the C code.  Look in the build scripts to see what is invoked on that file to create a `.c` from it.

Comment: See https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/distutils_guide.html#conversion-of-src-files-using-templates and https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/distutils_guide.html#other-files

Comment: The python functions that perform the conversion are here: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/distutils/conv_template.py

Comment: Thank you for reply. then using template, substituting string between @ and compile it? Its like numpy peculiar.